# How to reach used cipher key of current SSL connection under Firefox?

Tags: firefox, ssl, firefox-addon

I would like have one quick question. Is there any addon for Firefox or tool how to get session key generated from master secret during SSL handshake by which is encoded symmetrically whole client/server communication? I need it due to decoding of communication (POST/GET/etc..) via Wireshark or PCAP library. As I can see Firebug is showing decrypted communication so I hope there exist some proper ways how to reach this session key :)

Thank you all for a help.

Comment: I don't need to decrypt communication from Wireshark independently without having access to client side, which can be done with built in feature in Wireshark and requires private RSA key of the server. I am only asking whether there is any way (in Firefox) of getting final session key or premaster secret before is encrypted by server's public key and sent to the server. And then alternative use of this session key to decrypt captured communication by myself eg in Wireshark.

Comment: Firebug & Co. don't need to decrypt the traffic - they get the request before it is encrypted and the the response after it is decrypted in the browser. From all that I know, the session key is too level and isn't exposed to extensions.

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NSS_Key_Log_Format - not sure if that already existed when the question was asked, therefore only as a comment :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have good news for you.  You can actually get the Master-Key data that you need from both Firefox and Chrome.  And you can use the output file in Wireshark to decrypt the SSL/TLS traffic without the need for the private key from the SSL/TLS server.  Check out "Method 2" here: http://www.root9.net/2012/11/ssl-decryption-with-wireshark-private.html

As a tip, if you don't want to reboot your machine just open a command prompt and run:

set SSLKEYLOGFILE=c:\sslKeyLogFile.txt

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"

Since Firefox is being launched from the same session that you added the environment variable in, it will launch with that variable set.  Otherwise a restart of Windows will be required after setting it in the System settings dialogs.

I also want to point out that the answer from [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9244686/1212985) wasn't necessarily wrong, this is a fairly new feature.  It didn't make it into release until Wireshark 1.6.

Comment: This sounds useful for DHE cipher suites too (where having the server's private key wouldn't be enough).

Comment: Firefox 48+ disables this by default, but you can still use it in their "developer edition".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Wireshark then the pre master secret will be of no use for you (you refer to it as 'cipher key' in your question).

Wireshark can only decrypt traffic if you specify the RSA private key of the server, which doesn't change on every connection unlike the pre master secret. However, you can't get that through your browser or anything else for obvious reasons.

If you want to decrypt SSL traffic I suggest using an intermediate proxy instead, like Fiddler. It does not passively capture traffic but proxies the traffic, which enables it to actually decrypt the data sent and received.

Comment: Nice suggestion with proxy, I will try it later. Right now I am still looking for no proxy solution. For clear by 'cipher key' I meant 'session key'. More in the first comment to the question above.